# How To add ng-model dynamically inside angular.forEach

Tags: angularjs

This is what I append to my modal on load, and it's working fine, except the checkbox row.

```
//$scope.items is retrieved by an api, and looks something like this.
 $scope.items[0] = ['delivered' : true, 'status': 'delivered']
 $scope.items[1] = ['delivered': false, 'status': 'pending']

angular.element('.row-modal').empty();
request.success(function(response) {
    $scope.paymentTransactionServices = response;

    angular.forEach($scope.paymentTransactionServices, function(value, index) {
        var deliveredBy = value.deliveredBy ? value.deliveredBy.email : null;
        angular.element('#table-services').append('<tr class = "row-modal">' +
            '<td>' + value.title + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + deliveredBy + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + '<label class="checkbox-inline">' +
            ' <input type="checkbox" ng-model=' + $scope.paymentTransactionServices[index].delivered + ' ng-change="print()" />' + value.status + '</label> </td>' +
            '<td>' + value.delivery_date + '</td>' +
            '</tr>'
        );
    })
```

What I expect is that if "delivered" is false, the checkbox should notbe checked and if true then it should be checked. And on click, i want to fire a function but it's not working...

Comment: you are using an input inside label tag and without closing tag?

Comment: ng-model expects a variable. not its value. Instead of `{{value.delivered}}` try `$scope.items[index].delivered`

Comment: i tried it and when i inspected it, my ng-model value was = "true" but the checkbox wasn't checked and when i clicked on the checkbox the function wasn't fired. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never alter the dom like that, as this may result in unexpected errors and memory leaks in you application.

You should always use directives & components for this kind of stuff.

What you should do, in your template, is:

```
<table id="table-services">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Delivered by</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Delivery date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="service in paymentTransactionServices" class="row-modal">
        <td>{{ service.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ service.deliveredBy.email || null }}</td>
        <td>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="service.delivered" ng-change="print()" />
            {{ service.status }}
          </label>
        </td>
        <td>{{ service.delivery_date | date }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah, using a directive worked. It took me a while because I'm not familiar with directives, but it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to check a checkbox, you must add **checked** attribute to your HTML element. In the above case, there is no checked attributed on that element.

On the other hand, I have a doubt if click event exists on checkbox. Kindly use **change** instead.

Check if the below works

`input type="checkbox" checked={{value.delivered}} (change)=print()`

Comment: not working still... I changed the ng-checked value to be  `$scope.paymentTransactionServices[index].delivered` like it was suggested but still it didn't work, even if when i inspect it, `ng-checked = "true"`...

Comment: Try this,input type="checkbox" [checked]=value.delivered (change)=print().This worked for me.Use checked instead of ng-checked

Comment: can you please write it as a code as it's still not working for me?

Comment: This an AngularJS (1) question, not Angluar 4+.